# Chamisha Vetish'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred ninety-five?

### ?חמישה ותשעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 295.

If there are any treatments of lazy gematria here, I want them to be enlightening.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred ninety-four entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: Why is this the only mi-yodeya-sereis without the tag number? FTR I don't think any should have that tag. The series clearly has to do with numbers. Kind of like how we did not put any other tags with purim-torah-injest.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks; fixed. These questions definitely have to do with numbers, so I think the tag is appropriate. The reason we don't tag P"T questions with other tags is to make it absolutely clear that they are exceptions to our normal seriousness standards.

Comment: No doubt they have to do with numbers. I just feel they clog the tag from the other numbers questions, and besides, anyone looking for one of these can easily find it by way of the mi-yodeya-series tags. I'm not going to fight to change this or anything; I just mention it as I was already commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380044/jewish/Meditations-for-Troubled-Times.htm

> And for the blessing "R'tzei" ["Favor"], have in mind that the word
>   "r'tzei" [spelled reish (=200), tzadi (=90), hei (=5), = 295] has the
>   numerical value of the name Elokim spelled out with hei.
>
> "Elokim spelled out with hei" is: alef (1) lamed (30) pei (80), lamed
>   (30) mem (40) dalet (4), hei (5), hei (5), yud (10) vav (6) dalet (4),
>   mem (40) mem (40) =295.
>
> This is because the word "r'tzei" is the same letters as the word
>   "tzara" [which means "trouble"], and this is the secret meaning of the
>   verse "….and it is a time of trouble to Jacob, but he will be saved
>   from it" (Jeremiah 30:7); this "trouble" ["tzara"] is [the secret of
>   the name] Elokim spelled out with hei.

Answer (score 3):

Various online sources give the number of discovered pages of [the Aleppo codex (*keser Aram Tzova*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo_Codex) as 295. (Others give 294. I suppose the discrepancy may be due to one of the two late discoveries of single pages, but don't know.)